# how to find number of consecutive decreases(increases)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

how to find number of consecutive decreases(increases)

I have a dataframe which has 500K rows and 12 columns for months and include start and end month. Every columns represent a month. I need to compare every rows, i-th month and (i+1)-th month in range (startMonth, endmonth). (Ps: range is not constant. Everty row has different range size.)

Condition: If start month > end month, I should see "Neg99 = -999"

Here is my example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1016,1017,1018]
data = {'M_1': [3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 6, 6, 6,0,0,2,0,2],
        'M_2': [2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 5, 5, 5,1,1,1,1,2],
        'M_3': [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 4, 4,1,1,0,2,2],
        'M_4': [0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3,1,1,0,0,0],
        'M_5': [1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2,1,1,0,0,0],
        'M_6': [2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1,1,1,0,0,0],
        'M_7': [3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0,0,1,0,0,0],
        'M_8': [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,0,0,0,0,0],
        'M_9': [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'M_10': [0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'M_11': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'M_12': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0]}



startMonth = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5,1,1,1,1,1],
                          columns=['start'],index=idx)
endMonth = pd.DataFrame([12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 2,12,12,2,2,2],
                        columns=['end'], index=idx)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
Neg99 = -999
```

I wrote bool array for date range;

```
arr_bool = (np.less_equal.outer(startMonth.start, range(1,13)) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(endMonth.end, range(1,13))
            )

masked=df1.filter(regex='M_[0-9]').mask(~arr_bool)
```

I need to find consecutive decreases and increases for every rows.

- Here is decreases code;

```py
# Consecutive Decreases
decr = (np.diff(np.hstack((masked.values, np.zeros((masked.values.shape[0], 1)))), axis=1) > 0).argmin(axis=1)

final_decr = pd.DataFrame(decr,
                      index=idx, columns=['decr'])


final_decr.decr= np.select( condlist = [startMonth.start > endMonth.end],
                           choicelist = [Neg99],
                           default = final_decr.decr)
```

- Here is increasees code;

```py
incr = (np.diff(np.hstack((masked.values, np.zeros((masked.values.shape[0], 1)))), axis=1) < 0).argmin(axis=1)

final_incr = pd.DataFrame(incr,
                      index=idx, columns=['incr'])
final_incr.incr= np.select( condlist = [startMonth.start > endMonth.end],
                           choicelist = [Neg99],
                           default = final_incr.incr)
```

And finally, My expected outputs are;

```
Final increase table (.csv);
idx,my_results,expected_result
1001,0,0
1002,3,3
1003,1,1
1004,4,4
1005,0,0
1006,0,0
1007,0,0
1008,1,1
1009,0,0
1010,1,1
1011,0,3
1012,0,0
1013,-999,-999
1014,5,1
1015,6,1
1016,0,0
1017,0,2
1018,0,0

Final decrease table (.csv);
idx,my_result,expected_result
1001,3,3
1002,0,0
1003,0,0
1004,0,0
1005,0,0
1006,0,0
1007,0,0
1008,0,0
1009,1,1
1010,0,0
1011,0,0
1012,0,3
1013,-999,-999
1014,0,0
1015,0,0
1016,0,2
1017,0,0
1018,0,0

Final NoChange table (.csv);
idx,my_result,expected_result
1001,0,0
1002,0,0
1003,0,0
1004,0,0
1005,3,3
1006,11,11
1007,11,11
1008,0,0
1009,0,0
1010,0,0
1011,0,0
1012,0,0
1013,-999,-999
1014,0,0
1015,0,0
1016,0,0
1017,0,0
1018,2,0

Thanks for your advice!
```

Comment: I have the deja vu that I see this question somewhere.

Comment: @QuangHoang I didn't get any answer and I asked again. 
I've got little problem  with idx=1012 (decrease output), idx=1011 (increase output)

Comment: why should decrease at idx=1012 is 3?

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated output. idx=1012 (increase output should be 3), idx=1011 (decrease output should be 3).

Comment: Now I understand your question, the title is misleading. You want to find **when** the longest consecutive incr/decr starts, not the **number** of consecutive incr/decr???

Comment: Yes, **when** the longest consecutive **starts**. Actually, I could calculate but idx=1012(inc) starts columns should be M_4 also idx=1011(decr) should be M_4(because starts mounth=4).
However, due to arr_bool and argmin function, fot these indexes, my solution gives me 0. 
Consequently, I couldn't handled this problem.

Comment: @patronlargibi when decreasing is concerned, why for idx=1005 you expect 0? the decreasing sequence starts at the M_6 so I understand from the explanation that you wanted 5

Comment: @Ben.T when scanning row, firstly look startMonth. Such as, if StartMonth = 2 and endMonth=10 for idx=1014, our scope should M_2 to M_10.
So, idx=1005, StartMonth=1 and we should start M_1 column to M_12. 
M_1 = 1 and M_2=1, so no increasing or decreasing. So, we should get 0.

Comment: @patronlargibi I think increase and decrease results are mixed up. why for idx = 1001 increase is 3 while obviously with a startMonth at 1 and values are 3 then 2 then 1 then 0 from M_1 to M_4, so drecreasing. I'm sorry if I misunderstand again the question

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry :/ @Ben.T

Answer (score 0):

So I think instead of using `argmin`, you can use [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) after renaming the column to get an integer value of the position. Then remove the value of the `startMonth` such as:

```
incr = (df1.rename(columns={col:int(col.split('_')[1]) for col in masked.columns})
           .diff(-1, axis=1) < 0).mask(~arr_bool).idxmin(axis=1) - startMonth.start
decr = (df1.rename(columns={col:int(col.split('_')[1]) for col in masked.columns})
           .diff(-1, axis=1) > 0).mask(~arr_bool).idxmin(axis=1) - startMonth.start
```

Then you can do the `np.select` as you do, or probably just a `.illna(-999)` should be enough as I think with this solution everywhere you have nan in the result will be where your condition `startMonth.start > endMonth.end` is met

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working correctly. 

I will edit example data for you (add idx=1014 and 1015).
increasing result should be idx= 1014 and 1015 -> 1 but we see 5 (for 1014), 6 (for 1015)

Comment: @patronlargibi i edited the method using `idxmin` and I think this time it works.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much (: I would prefere ```np.select``` because sometimes I have multliple conditions. So, ```np.select``` very useful operator for me. 

If you have time, I have one more question. You found increasing&decreasing. How can we find time of no change. Its question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490382/how-can-i-find-the-count-of-first-consecutive-times-that-the-value-remained-unch)

Comment: @patronlargibi I saw your other question and think if you use the same method than above but with `== 0` instead of `<0` or `> 0` it should work?

Comment: Its almost done! But if startMonth=1 and endMonth=2, not work correctly. I added new idx, (1016to1018)
Such as, idx=1016 for decreasing, should be 2 but I saw 0.
Idx=1017 for increasing, should be 2 but I saw 0.
I am comparing i-th and i+1-th months. So, i=2(endmonth), I should look i=3rd month.
Thank you for your answer (:

Comment: If I add 1 to endMonth (like ```endMonth = endMonth+1```), I can get correct results in this sample dataset.
However, when I run real dataset, I get this error code.
```TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype```

Comment: @patronlargibi good I was not sure how to fix your problem. for the TypeError, it means some values in your data are not numeric, you need to fix this before using the above method. Maybe using `pd.to_numeric` or you need to remove rows that don't have numeric values

Comment: I don't know why, first column transform True/False. I use ```.astype('float')``` and cannot transform because of ```nan```.
Before ```idxmin```, I should use ```.fillna(0).astype('float')```

But this time, I lost idx of startMonth=4 (startMonth bigger than 1) rows.