# Count how many consecutive TRUEs on each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to count how many consecutive TRUEs on each row and I solved that part myself but I need to find a solution for this part: If a row starts with FALSE then result must be 0. There is a sample dataset below. Can you recommend me your tips to how to solve this.

PS. my original question is at the link below.

[how to find number of consecutive decreases(increases)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397021/how-to-find-number-of-consecutive-decreasesincreases/)

```py
Sample data, .csv file
idx,Expected Results,M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4,M_5,M_6,M_7,M_8,M_9,M_10,M_11,M_12
1001,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1002,3,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1003,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1004,4,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1005,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1006,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1007,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1008,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1009,0,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
1010,1,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
1011,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1013,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1014,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1015,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1016,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1017,2,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1018,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
```

After John Solution;
How can I count the Trues till I see the "False"

```py
result = df.where(df[0], 0)

idx,M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4,M_5,M_6,M_7,M_8,M_9,M_10,M_11,M_12
1001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1002,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1003,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1004,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1006,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1007,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1008,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1009,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1010,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
1011,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1013,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1014,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1015,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1016,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1017,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
1018,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: why is first row expected 0? when it has 3 TRUE?

Comment: idx=1001 started with FALSE, so it could be 0. If starts with FALSE, number of True is never important.

Comment: so for rows having 2 groups of consecutive Trues? eg: `T,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,T` what is the number for this example?

Comment: It should be 3. We should counting True until the First False. ```T,T,T,F``` and Stop. We should see 3.
If start with False, ```F,T,T.....``` Doesn't metter. We should see 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.argmin`. You needn't prefilter your df, it will handle rows starting with `False` correctly.

```
df.loc[:, 'M_1':'M_12'].values.argmin(1)
#array([0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0])
```

Note that this assumes there is at least one `False` in every row.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[:, 'M_1':'M_12'].apply(np.logical_and.accumulate, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse values of columns `M-1` - `M-12` using negation `'~'`. I.e, `True` to `False` and vice-versa. Doing `cummax` to separate first group of consecutive `True` (note: at this point `True` represent `False-value` and 'False' represent `True-value`). Doing another negation on the result of `cummax` and finally `sum`

```
(~(~df.drop(['idx'], 1)).cummax(1)).sum(1)


Out[503]:
0     0
1     3
2     1
3     4
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     1
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    1
14    0
15    2
16    0
dtype: int64
```